# Something like `watch` but of files rather than directories

Tags: node.js, build, npm

The `watch` NPM package watches directories (see [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/watch) for more on it).  I'd like a package similar to `watch` but where it can watch files that I specify.

I know there are countless NPM packages that can watch files. What I'm looking for is a package that:

1. does not depend on a build tool such as Gulp, Grunt, Broccoli, etc.;
2. is as lightweight as the `watch` package, not heavyweight such as `nodemon`, `watchman`, etc.;
3. is popular (downloaded many times everyday).

Comment: https://github.com/yuanchuan/node-watch wrapper supports watching of individual files.

Comment: @snozza seems https://github.com/kimmobrunfeldt/chokidar-cli is better than that but both aren't widely used